# XPath to count total number of string tokens of several nodes in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xslt, xpath, libxml2

Is there a neat XPath expression to count string tokens of a set of nodes? Eg;

```
<set>
  <hi>hello, there, world</hi>
  <hi>foo, bar</hi>
</set>
```

The answer I want for the above example is the value `5`. The first `<hi>` has 3 tokens. The second `<hi>` has 2 tokens.

The `<set>` may contain any number of `<hi>` nodes, each of which may contain any number of tokens. A token is a string separated by a comma followed by space.

I've tried;

```
 <xsl:value-of select="count(str:tokenize(/set//hi, ', '))"/>
```

but that returns the number of tokens of the first node, ie. `3`.

I'm using XSLT 1.0. (PHP libxml version 2.7.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of thing that's easy in XPath 2.0, but unfortunately requires some extra work in XPath 1.0. There are a number of ways you can do this with an extra step. This is the one I would use:

```
<xsl:variable name="tmp">
  <xsl:for-each select="//hi">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ', ')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="count(str:tokenize($tmp, ', '))"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You would need the expressive power of XPath 2.0 or XQuery 1.0 like `count(/set/hi/tokenize(., ', '))` to do it with a single expression.

With XSLT 1.0 you need to iterate and sum up the values, perhaps using a result tree fragment as a data structure for intermediary results which you then convert (with `exsl:node-set`) to a node-set for summing up the pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Given your definition

> A token is a string separated by a comma followed by space.

... all you want to do is count the number of commas and add 1 for each string.

Here is a bit of a hack that works in XSLT 1.0, and it exploits a `translate()` idiom that sometimes proves useful.  Think about what it is doing (it takes a moment to sink in for a first-time user of the idiom).

```
T:\ftemp>type commas.xml
<set>
  <hi>hello, there, world</hi>
  <hi>foo, bar</hi>
</set>
T:\ftemp>xslt commas.xml commas.xsl
5
T:\ftemp>type commas.xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="set">
  <xsl:variable name="commas">
    <xsl:for-each select="hi">
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,translate(.,',',''),'')"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="string-length($commas)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
T:\ftemp>
```

Comment: I can't see the idiom that takes a moment to sink in for a first-time user.

Comment: The second argument to translate is a list of characters to be translated, and the third argument is what to translate them to (or empty to remove them).  So I'm doing two removals because the third argument is empty in both calls to `translate()`.  The inner call removes all commas from the source string, thus making a control string of every character that isn't a comma.  The outer call removes all of those characters from the source string, thus leaving only commas.  It is a handy hack for XSLT 1 ... I don't think I've used it for XSLT 2 yet in my production work.